# ADLS Gen2 --> ACL on a folder level

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I have a question regarding permissions for ADLS Gen2

**short description:**
I have a Gen2 storage account and created a container.

Folder Structure looks something like this

```
StorageAccount1
  --->Container1
       --->Folder1
          --->Files 1....n
```

Also i have a service principal from a customer..
Now i have to provide the customer write only permission to only Folder1 (should not be able to delete files inside Folder1)

I have assigned the service principle below permissions in the Access control list

```
Container1 --> Execute    
Folder1 --> Write , Execute
```

with this the customer can now put data into this Folder1.. but how do i prevent him from deleting any files inside it? ( i dont wanna use SAS )
Or is there any other way other than ACL?

Please help :)

[ACL for ADLSgen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa24b.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please check if below can be worked.

- ACLs are the way to control access to be applied on the file and
  folder level unlike others which are for container level.
- Best practice is to always restrict access  using [(Azure RBAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)
  on the Storage Account/Container level  has several Azure built-in
  roles that you can assign to users, groups, service principals, and
  managed identities and then  combine with ACLs with more restrictive
  control on the file and folder level.

Ex: Storage Blob Data Contributor has read/write/delete permission .[Assign an Azure role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal#rbac-roles-for-blobs-and-queues)

- If the built-in roles don't meet the specific needs of your
  organization, you can create your own [Azure custom roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles).

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor)

To assign roles, you must be assigned a role that has role assignments write permission, such as Owner or User Access Administrator at the scope you are trying to assign the role.

**To create a custom role with customized permissions.**

Create a new file C:\CustomRoles\customrole1.json like example below. The ID should be set to null on initial role creation as a
new ID is generated automatically.

```
{
       "Name": "Restrict user from  delete operation on Storage",
       "ID": null,
       "IsCustom": true,
       "Description": "This role will restrict the user from delete operation on the storage account. However, customer will be able to see the storage account, container, blob.",

  "Actions": [
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read",
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read",
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/generateUserDelegationKey/action"
  ],

  "NotActions": [
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/delete"
  ],

  "DataActions": [
"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read",
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/write",
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/move/action",
        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/add/action"
  ],

  "NotDataActions": [   
    "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/delete",
  ],


       "AssignableScopes": [

              "/subscriptions/dxxxx7-xxxx"
       ]
}
```

Using the above role definition, by running the below powershell script to create a custom role:

```
New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile "C:\CustomRoles\customrole1.json"
```

see below **References:** for details.

1. [How to restrict the user from upload/download or delete blob in
   storage account - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/how-to-restrict-the-user-from-upload-download-or-delete-blob-in/ba-p/1078687)
2. [Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor)

Also try to enable [soft delete](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/soft-delete-for-blobs-capability-for-azure-data-lake-storage-is-now-generally-available/) to restore delete actions if the role has delete permissions .

Though mentioned to not use .Just in case .Shared access signature (SAS) can be used to restrict access to blob container or an individual blob. Folder in blob storage is virtual and not a real folder. You may refer to the suggestion mentioned in this article

**References**

1. [permissions-are-required-to-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#which-permissions-are-required-to-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-contents)
2. [Cannot delete blobs from ADLS gen2 when connected via Private Endpoint - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/604725/cannot-delete-blobs-from-adls-gen2-when-connected.html#:%7E:text=Steps%20to%20reproduce%3A%201%20Create%20ADLS%20Gen2%20account.,Error%20from%20Azure%20Storage%20Explorer%20%2F%20azcopy%3A%20)
3. [Authorize with Azure Active Directory (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#permissions-for-calling-data-operations)

Comment: Hii @kavyasarboju-MT Thank you for the explanation :) but can you please explain how to combine custom RBAC and ACL.. so i have to provide the service principal the RBAC with write and no delete role and then again in folder level ACL give the service principal write and execute? if so then now the user can write in any folder inside the container right?  so RBAC with only no delete and ACL with folder level?  also i am using ADLS gen2 with hierarchical namespace enabled so directories are real i guess..